# wp attach image based on category

Tags: wordpress, function

I have this function to display image by category :

```
/*default thumbnails for posts if no thumbnail is set, based on the selected category*/
add_filter('genesis_get_image', 'default_thumb'); 
function default_thumb($output) { 
if(!$output) { 
$default_cat_thumbs = array( 
'now' => 'now.jpg', 
'news' => 'Volleyball-Club_Leipzig.gif'); 
foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) { 
if (array_key_exists($category->slug, $default_cat_thumbs)) { 
$url = 'http://www.mepanorama.com/wp-content/images/'.$default_cat_thumbs[$category->slug]; 
$output = '<img width="120" height="140" src="'.$url.'" class="alignleft" alt="" title="" />'; 
} 
} 
} 
return $output; 
}
```

works great to show images in my archive page for category "now" for example. like here

http://www.mepanorama.com/category/now/

but i want to show image for this category in posts, the problem is that my permalink does not include category , so is there is a way to pull the category name lets say from my breadcrumb?

example post 
http://www.mepanorama.com/180193/test/

Comment: [This may help you](http://wordpresshero.com/hacks/category-images-hack.html/) or [maybe this plugin](http://coffee2code.com/archives/2004/06/27/plugin-category-images/).

Comment: thanks , but I try to avoid plugins as much as I can , for the other function its basically same what I have.

Answer (score 0):

You can test if a post is in a category with in_category:

```
if (in_category( "now")) :
    // do stuff
end
```

You can also use get_the_category() to retrieve all categories for a specific post.

```
foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) :
    echo '<img src="http://www.mepanorama.com/wp-content/images/' . $category->cat_ID . '.jpg\" />'; 
end
```

Hope that helps.